# AHK how can I open a file by vim

Tags: vim, autohotkey

I'm the beginner of AHK.
I want to open some files by vim. Here my manually steps:

```
1. Open context menu by right click the file 
2. select "Edit with vim"
```

Now, I want to map a shortcut key, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for example.

I can open a file by

```
^1::run c:\vim.exe "d:\desktop\1.py
```

But, how can I get the full path which has been selected?

Comment: If you *copy* the file, the `ClipBoard` variable will contain its path. Copying, of course, can be achieved by sending `CTRL + c`.

Comment: Well, is there any way to get the full path about the file which was selected?

Comment: The clipboard will contain the full path if you copy it!

Comment: You could also use the [Explorer.ahk Library](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60985-get-paths-of-selected-items-in-an-explorer-window/) to get information out of an explorer window.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already mentioned, if you copy a file from windows explorer and access the %clipboard% variable from Autohotkey, you'll get the absoute path of the file, so you could just do

```
^1::

    Send, ^c
    Run, c:\vim.exe %clipboard%

return
```

or even

```
Run, vim %clipboard%
```

if you add the exe's location to the 'Path' Environmental Variable

ps.: I tested with this and it was working

```
^1::

    Send, ^c
    Run, notepad %clipboard%

return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it cannot work. `^c` cannot get the filepath.
I tried to print the **%clipboard%** by `MsgBox`, it shows nothing.

Comment: What happens if you try to copy the file manually, and then do `MsgBox, %clipboard%`? Also, what OS are you using and what autohotkey version? :)
PS.: does the clipboard variable even work with plain text?

Comment: The MsgBox will show the content which I copy it before. For example, I copy "abc" from a file, and "abc" will show after click `ctrl + 1`

Comment: By the way, the system which I using is Windows 7, and **clipbrd.exe** is not exists in win7 (only exists in win xp).

Comment: I don't know much about the clipbrd.exe, but the thing I know is that this code works for me perfectly under Windows 8! I have no idea why it doesn't get the file path for you. :S What version of autohotkey are you using? (I would recomment AutoHotKey_L)